# Can't cd into a directory named with accented characters

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, charset

I have the following folders on a CentOS 7 Droplet. They were added via FTP from a French operating system.

- Evénement 1
- Evénement 2
- Evénement 3

The accented character (é) is replaced with a question mark when I do `ls`.

I cannot `cd` into these folders.

I have tried several suggestions from around the web without luck. Including:

```
cd Evénement\ 1
cd "Evénement 1"
cd "Ev?nement 1" (copying the exact output from ls)
cd Ev\nement\ 1
cd Ev\énement\ 1
cd Ev\351énement\ 1 (because ls -b outputs them like that)
```

Here is the output of `locale`.

```
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: try temporary set LANG=fr_CA.UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

use single quotes and/or `tab` (autocomplete), like following:

```
mbp:~ alexus$ mkdir 'Evénement'
mbp:~ alexus$ cd 'Evénement'
mbp:Evénement alexus$ pwd
/Users/alexus/Evénement
mbp:Evénement alexus$ cd ..
mbp:~ alexus$ cd Evénement/
mbp:Evénement alexus$
```

Comment: Thanks. When I make a new directory via the command line it works well as it does for you. But these are all files that were added via FTP and that seems to have caused the issue since I can't get into them via command line.

Comment: @ScreenWatcher You really tried `tab` autocompletion?

Comment: @screenwatcher yes, second try was with `tab`.

Comment: When I try tab autocompletion, it finds several folders with the same start to the filename, so doesn't autocomplete. I can hit tab twice to see the proposed names. Is there a way for me to autocomplete with one of those proposed names?

Comment: @ScreenWatcher Type `Ev` then hit `tab`)

Comment: @alexus, I have tried that, it doesn't work since there are multiple folders that start with Ev.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cd "Ev*nement 1"`. `cd "Ev?nement 1"` (typing the ? yourself instead of copying it from the shell's output) may also work. My guess is that the question mark in the `ls` output is not a real question mark but rather a special character indicating the shell's failure to decode the character.

Can you post the output of `locale`?

Comment: Thanks, I tried those suggestions without success. I have added the output of `locale` to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue. I changed the character encoding from Unicode (UTF-8) to Western (ISO Latin 1) for my actual terminal program, iTerm2. I did this my modifying the profile that connects to this server as follows:

iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Profile > Terminal > Character encoding

Now the accented characters show correctly and I can cd into them without trouble.

Thanks again to those who tried to help.